# ¿Cómo enviar y recibir datos con un FloatingActionButton?

Tags: android

Tengo un `activity` normal que pasa datos a otra `activity` que tiene un `FloatingActionButton`, al ejecutar, cuando quiero entrar a la actividad con el `FloatingActionButton` me dice que se detiene la app.

```
public class tutorial__m2 extends AppCompatActivity {
int contador;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tutorial__m2);

    Bundle recibir= this.getIntent().getExtras();
    contador=recibir.getInt("a");


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){


            Intent a=new Intent(tutorial__m2.this, Matematicas3.class);

            contador =contador;
            a.putExtra("b", contador);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_back_in, R.anim.zoom_back_out);
            tutorial__m2.this.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Este es el error que me aparece:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de enviar y recibir datos con un `FloatingButton`?

Comment: Añade el código de la segunda actividad donde recibes los datos por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalmente ese error ocurre porque abres la segunda actividad sin ningún extra, es decir, puede que estés usando `getIntent().getExtras()` pero como no tiene nada que recibir te manda `null`.

Para solucionar ese error es checar si realmente hay datos, es decir, `getIntent().getExtras() != null` que recibir con esto:

```
Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle!= null) {//Aquí compruebas que no se encuentra vacío
        //En caso que si existan datos aquí recibes el valor y codificas lo que quieres...
       } else {
        //Aquí controlas que quieres que haga en caso de no existir datos que recibir
         Log.d(TAG,"Lo sentimos, no hay datos que recibir");

       }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Amigo, me sirvio mucho <3 :D